# Finitely-Lebesgue measure

Tags: measure-theory

I am studying a book by Shilov-Gurevich on Daniell integration (the functional analytic approach to defining integral more or less). There is the funny notion of a finitely-Lebesgue measure which I was unable to understand and find any where else. The definition is

> Given any $\sigma$ ring $U$ and a countably additive finite measure
>   $\mu$, $U$ is called $\sigma_{\mu}$ ring if every subset $Z\in U$ of
>   measure zero also belongs to $U$. In this case $\mu$ is called
>   finitely-Lebesgue measure.

I dont really understand this definition since $Z$ also belongs to $U$, this makes no sense to me. I searched for finitely-Lebesgue measure but could not find it anywhere neither. Please let me know if there is a similiar notion with other terminology, or if you understand this definition.

Comment: Though I don't have the book, what I expect is intended is: "for every $Z\in U$ of measure zero, *every subset $Y\subseteq Z$ also belongs to $U$*". This would then be a version of the notion of [complete measure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_measure).

Comment: Thanks it makes much more sense. I will compare this with the examples given later to see if this is a good candidate.